# does this Stream object create an infinite list of chimp objects or just one chimp object?

Tags: java, java-stream

In the OCP studybook there is a line of code I don't entirely understand. It goes like this:

```
Stream<String> infinite = Stream.generate(() -> "chimp");
```

Does this create an infinite stream with just one element called chimp or does it infinitly generate chimp strings. Thank you.

Comment: try it out to see

Comment: You can either look up the documentation or try it out yourself .... you really show no effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen unless there is a terminal operation in the stream pipeline please see [Stream operations and pipelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) section. For example this code:

```
infinite.forEach(System.out::println); // chimp ....
```

will print infinitive number of `chimp` Strings. 
However this line will print only one String

```
infinite.limit(1).forEach(System.out::println); // chimp
```

On the other side

```
Stream.generate(() -> "chimp");
```

Has no effect, there no terminal operation in the stream's pipeline.

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy;
>   executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually
>   perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when
>   traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the
>   given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until
>   the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly, The stream will only start generating those chimp strings when a terminal operation method like forEach(System.out::println) operates on the Stream instance?

Comment: @Maurice, yes it will. You can apply as many intermediate operations as you want, but they have no effect unless there is a terminal one.  From java doc: Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

Answer (score 2):

> **Stream java.util.stream.Stream.generate(Supplier s)**
>
> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier. This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

It will create an infinite `Stream`, which means a `Stream` with infinite number of elements. All the elements will be the same `String` instance, since `"chimp"` will always return the same `String` instance from the `String` pool.

If you change it to

```
Stream<String> infinite = Stream.generate(() -> new String("chimp"));
```

each `String` element of this `Stream` will be a unique instance.